# RSPEC - ways to create Models with different parameters / avoid duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have 3 tests for a Model, and the main difference between them all is the number of parameters passed when each is created.  I'm pretty much running the same expectation on each version of the Model to boot, so there is a lot of duplication.  I was just wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing this.  Here is my code:

```
    describe Item do 
  subject {Item.new( :report_id => 15 ,  :name => 'Gas' ,  :tax_id => 1 ,  :category_id => 15 ,  :sub_category_id => 1 ,  :job_id => 1 , :total => 20 )}
  let(:tax) {Tax.where(id: subject.tax_id).first}
  let(:sub_category) {SubCategory.where(id: subject.sub_category_id).first}


  it 'Calculate with just Total' do
    subject.name.should be == 'Gas'    
    subject.set_nil_values
    sub_category.should_receive(:taxable).and_return(sub_category.taxable)
    tax.should_receive(:rate).and_return(tax.rate)
    sub_category.should_receive(:tax_adjustment).and_return(sub_category.tax_adjustment)
    subject.calculate_tax
    subject.calculate_cost
    subject.cost.should be_within(0.01).of(17.70)
    subject.tax_amount.should be_within(0.01).of(2.30)
    subject.save
  end

end

  describe Item do 
    subject {Item.new(:report_id => 15 ,  :name => 'Gas' ,  :tax_id => 1 ,  :category_id => 15 ,  :sub_category_id => 1 ,  :job_id => 1 ,  :tax_override => 2.30 ,  :total => 20  )}
    let(:sub_category) {SubCategory.where(id: subject.sub_category_id).first}


    it 'Calculate with tax override' do
      @tax = Tax.find(subject.tax_id)
      subject.name.should be == 'Gas'
      tax = Tax.find_by_id(subject.tax_id)

      subject.set_nil_values
      sub_category.should_receive(:taxable).exactly(1).times.and_return(sub_category.taxable)
      tax.should_receive(:rate).exactly(1).times.and_return(tax.rate)
      sub_category.should_receive(:tax_adjustment).exactly(1).times.and_return(sub_category.tax_adjustment)
      subject.calculate_tax
      subject.calculate_cost
      subject.cost.should be_within(0.01).of(17.70)
      subject.tax_amount.should be_within(0.01).of(2.30)
      subject.save
    end

     describe Item do 
        subject {Item.new(  :report_id => 16 ,  :name => 'Gas' ,  :tax_id => 1 ,  :category_id => 15 ,  :sub_category_id => 1 ,  :job_id => 1 ,  :tax_override => 1.15 ,  :unclaimed_tax => 1.15 ,  :total => 20 
          )}
        let(:sub_category) {SubCategory.where(id: subject.sub_category_id).first}


        it 'Calculate with Unclaimed Tax' do
          @tax = Tax.find(subject.tax_id)
          subject.name.should be == 'Gas'
          tax = Tax.find_by_id(subject.tax_id)

          subject.set_nil_values
          sub_category.should_receive(:taxable).exactly(1).times.and_return(sub_category.taxable)
          tax.should_receive(:rate).exactly(1).times.and_return(tax.rate)
          sub_category.should_receive(:tax_adjustment).exactly(1).times.and_return(sub_category.tax_adjustment)
          subject.calculate_tax
          subject.calculate_cost
          subject.cost.should be_within(0.01).of(17.70)
          subject.tax_amount.should be_within(0.01).of(1.15)
          subject.unclaimed_tax.should be_within(0.01).of(1.15)
          subject.save
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use factories and [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) gem.
Also, please format your code appropriately, it's difficult to read.